# how to use npm init <initializer> for my package? command not found error

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts, npx

I have a package named: create-ts-starter in npm registry https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-ts-starter.

I want to use it as my project starter with command `npm init ts-starter` as it explained in https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/init

but when I run it, it just show me error:

```
npm init ts-starter
npx: installed 1 in 1.65s
command not found: create-ts-starter
```

this is the Github repo https://github.com/saostad/node-typescript-starter

what am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure but am curious to find out as well. The docs do mention `npm package named create-<initializer>`, so possibly your repo/npm-package name might need to start with "create-"

Comment: it will work even without repo, repo is just optional information that we can provide. I think it should be something related to this part `and then have its main bin executed – presumably creating or updating package.json and running any other initialization-related operations.` of doc.

Comment: just making sure, do you have npm 6+?

Comment: node v 13.3.0 & npm 6.13.1

Answer (score 0):

I found out what I was missing! it needs a "bin" field in package.json file and a script to run the rest of the process. now if you run `npm init ts-starter` it does all things I wanted :)